# Unreasonably slow response to running a simple custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple test spreadsheet, that tests whether a cell is bold.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZNEq8oKALVFlLHHWmOwFIaQsvYSS9kD7uDCfI4h7rks/edit?usp=sharing

I have attached a simple function as follows:

```
/**
return val2 if a1Notation is bold, else return val2
*/
function isBold(a1Notation, val1, val2) {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(a1Notation);

    if(cell.getFontWeight() == 'bold')
        return val1;
    return val2;
}
```

However, running this script on one cell takes a ridiculously long time. > 30 seconds.

Can anyone shed light on the reason it takes this long? Any way of speeding this up?

Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm the issue but can't provide a fix. When debugging the function with the same parameters it is fast. Tried assigning the Worksheet to a variable that gets loaded on opening the spreadsheet to avoid reloading it on every recalculation but that didn't help. Also tried explicitly just getting the first cell before checking for boldness, no success. Very weird issue.

Comment: even if it wanst slow, your  custom function wont work because its reading parameters from somewhere else and not  its inputs thus you will get incorrect results.

Comment: Can you explain? The formula works for me, it's just slow.

Comment: The crazy thing is, this formula was instantaneous no more than a week ago. And since the weekend, it's slowed down. So baffling.

Comment: Hey @ZigMandel , the code works currently, and was instantaneous no more than a week ago. Unsure what you mean.

Comment: look here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions where it mentions "deterministic". its not well explained but basically google will cache your function return value based only on input parameters. so it wont return the right value after your range contents change value.

Comment: now, the delay is a separate issue which is likely a bug that should be reported on their issues page

Comment: Makes, sense, I didn't check for that. Thanks for elaborating.